# Изменение представления LocalDate

Tags: java

Нужно строке в формате `dd/MM/yyyy` изменить представление на `dd.MM.yyyy` и вернуть `LocalDate`.

Получить новую строку в нужном формате удалось, но как конвертировать это в `LocalDate`, чтобы он не вернулся в формат `yyyy/MM/dd` не пойму.

```
public static LocalDate convertStingToLocalDate(final String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    String newFormat = localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    
    return null;
}
```

Пробовал идею:

```
LocalDate.parse(newFormat, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

Возвращается строка в формате `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: откуда и куда возвращается? чтобы был нужный формат нужно всего лишь применить нужный формат. Ведь LocalDate это не строка, и то, что вы видите - форматирование LocalDate в строку в указанном формате.

Comment: @Эникейщик изначально приходит строка условно 12/09/2021, нужно вернуть LocalDate в формате 12.09.2021

Comment: еще раз - у LocalDate НЕТ формата 12.09.2021. И вообще никакого формата нет. Если вам нужно вернуть такую строку, то возвращайте просто свою переменную newFormat